# Bash/zsh: get substring from the last match in a string

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

In a shell script I have a variable `$PATH` which could look like this: `/foo8232/test874-ab/bar/test-82-x`. I now want to get a substring of this, getting as a result `test-82-x` in this specific case.

Thus I have to match the occurrences of `/test.*`, but only the last element OR from the end of the string. Whatever works best.

Any help on this?

**Edit:**
Thanks for providing so many solutions so quickly. A few of them don't work though. Not sure, but maybe the problem is, that my path actually has whitespaces and more looks like this: `/foo12323/test34 - 343bar/test - 234/test - 4323.txt`. Sorry that I didn't mentioned it in the first place, if that causes troubles.

Comment: Aside: don't call your variable `PATH`.  That will affect which commands can be run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your specific path management, you've got the basename function :

```
basename /foo8232/test874-ab/bar/test-82-x
>>> test-82-x
```

or in a script :

```
#!/bin/bash
fullfilename=$(basename $1)
extension=${fullfilename##*.}
filename=${fullfilename%.*}

echo "fullfilename=$fullfilename"
echo "extension=$extension"
echo "filename=$filename"
```

which gives :

```
./file_name.sh /foo8232/test874-ab/bar/test-82-x
fullfilename=test-82-x
extension=
filename=test-82-x
```

Answer (score 2):

The following should be POSIX-compliant

```
BASE=$(basename $PATH)
if echo $BASE | grep "^test.*" > /dev/null; then
  # do something awesome
fi
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint with `basename`. That's a very simple solution :-)

Answer (score 2):

The last path element containing `test` could also be found with `sed`:

```
elem=$(echo $PATH | sed -r 's#.*/(test[^/]*).*#\1#')
```

Or without `-r` (using extended regular expressions):

```
elem=$(echo $PATH | sed 's#.*/\(test[^/]*\).*#\1#')
```

Comment: Unfortunately Mac OS X sed doesn't have `-r`.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Still doesn't work, but maybe because I've whitespaces in my path. Updated the question. Sorry for that.

Comment: Actually this should not be a problem.

Comment: `echo "/foo12323/test34 - 343bar/test - 234/test - 4323.txt" | sed 's#.*/\(test[^/]*\).*#\1#'` gives me `test - 4323.txt` .

Comment: Hmm, probably I did something else wrong. Will check later again. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

So you're looking for the last directory component that starts with `test`.

How about

```
IFS=/
for dir in $PATH; do
    case $dir in test*)
        match=$dir;;
    esac
done
```

Answer (score -1):

echo pwd | awk -F \/ '{print $NF}'|grep test

Comment: Doesn't work for me, but maybe because I've whitespaces in my path. Updated the question. Sorry for that.

Comment: why `echo pwd` ? That will just print "pwd". Unless you mean `echo \`pwd\``, but that's just the same as just `pwd`. Supposedly that should've been `echo $PATH` (as the variable in the question is called)